# Keras prediction time measurement: First value outlier

Tags: python, keras

I'm currently trying to measure the time, which a Keras (TF Back) model needs to make predictions. As this time might vary, i'm doing a sample of predicitons and calculate the mean and sample standard deviation of them. The code looks like this:

```
 timekeras = []
 for i in range(int(ANALYSIS_SAMPLE_SIZE)):
     timedummy = time.time()
     predskeras = model.predict ( np.array(test_data_list) )
     timekeras.append(time.time() - timedummy)
```

Now I noticed, that the sample standard deviation is always larger than the mean, which is a sign for some vast outliers. After looking at the list with the time measurements, I know now that the first prediction always takes about 10 times as long as those that follow. I guess the algorithm is somehow "remembering" that he did the exact same calculations right before and uses some of the already-calculated results?

Anyway, my question is now: In a real application scenario, the model won't make the same prediction multiple times right one after another, so my measured values are seemingly useless except for the first one. Does anybody have an idea how to do the same prediction a number of times, but always as if it wasn't done before, in order to do meaningful time measurements? And generally, just because I'm curious: Does anybody know why Keras is doing this, taking 10 times less time for doing a prediction again?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clear the session after every prediction. This way you will be able to get the predictions in a real-time context.

```
try:
   from keras import backend as K
except:
   from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
    
    K.clear_session()
    tf.reset_default_graph()
```